# Google App Engine NDB FloatProperty default value not working?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, default-value, app-engine-ndb

I'm working in Google App Engine, Python 2.7, Standard Environment, using the ndb datastore.  I'm doing some updates to some of my NDB models, and one of the updates requires me to add a new property (a floating-point number) to my "Restaurant" model.  In the past, when I've needed to add properties to a model, I've always liked how NDB lets you specify default values when defining the model, like so:

```
class Restaurant(ndb.Model):
    ... some properties ...
    resto_fullresyncstamp = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.0)
```

My understanding of this default value was, when the entity was fetched from the datastore, if there is no resto_fullresyncstamp property for a given entity, one is added to the local copy of the model, with the default value.  That way, I don't have to keep checking to see if everything is None, and I can assume the property will always have a value in my code.  So I should be able to do something like this ...

```
lastsync = ...
resto = Restaurant.query()....get()
if not resto:
    logging.warning("Failed to get restauraunt: %s" % username)
    self.error(404)
    return

if lastsync != 0.0 and resto.resto_fullresyncstamp > lastsync:
    logging.warning("Requiring client to perform full resynchronization")
    self.error(510)
    return
```

... and expect that, even if "resto_fullresyncstamp" is a new property in my model, and the particular restaurant has never had that property set explicitly anywhere, that I will still get a valid (0.0) value to compare against.

What I'm actually getting is this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~virt-som/1.406133528491612487/virtsom.py", line 5399, in post
if lastsync != 0.0 and resto.resto_fullresyncstamp > lastsync:

AttributeError: 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'resto_fullresyncstamp'
```

Shouldn't this work?  I've been working with NDB for ages, and I've used the "default" parameter in my Models like this successfully before.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works.

Whenever you add a new property to a existing model you have to put the old entities again into the datastore to get that property. To get it at all no matter what the default value is.

Comment: Well @janscas, manually adding the property by assigning a value to it seems to have sorted the problem out for me, but then what is the purpose of the "default" parameter? Why would you provide the property with a "default" value and then require the developer to manually assign the property a value before it can be used? It makes the "default" parameter worse than useless, it makes it misleading.  It also makes Google's own documentation wrong - [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema), complete with example, is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The default parameter does what it says. If you don't set it, it gets set to the default. BUT, that ONLY works in all entities that you save AFTER you change the model.

Comment: I'm sorry @janscas, but with all due respect, [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema) is exactly what I'm trying to do, and according to the article, when I add a new field to my entity, there will be entities already previously saved to the datastore, that don't have this new field.  To quote the article directly: "Whenever a Picture is read from Datastore num_votes and avg_rating will be populated (either with the value from Datastore, or the default specified in the model)."  This is what I'm expecting, and it's not working in the latest version of the API.

Comment: From the article you are reading: "Note that existing entries will not be automatically modified, a read-write of the entity is required before the new properties will be persisted to Datastore." You need to re-put the old entities to the datastore with the new schema. Hope this helps...

Comment: @SteveSauder another thing you can do that is very common is to use getattr on the model. like this: 'getattr(entity, property, default)' This way you will get a default value even if you didn't re-put the entity to update the schema.

Comment: I do understand that the entities need to be rewritten in order to have the new properties persisted.  But going back to the original post, I did exactly what the article says, and got an exception instead of the default value on read.  That’s my issue. Getattr is another good solution...!